# Volume bounded by a plane and parabolic cylinder

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of the region in the first octant bounded by $z=x^2+2$, $x=y=z=0$, and $x=2-y$. Let the order of integration be $dzdxdy$.

Here's what I did: $\int_0^2\int_0^{2-y}\int_2^{x^2+2} dzdxdy$.

Is the triple integral correct so far? I'm unsure of the values for $z$ since it was given that $z=0$ but graph of the parabolic cylinder starts at $z=2$.

Comment: Far as I consider, it's $$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-y}\int_0^{x^2+2} dzdxdy$$.

Comment: What @Oolongmilktea meant to say is that your bound are incorrect. If $z$ were the vertical axis, you would integrate from $z=0$ to the height $z = x^2 + 2$. This is because your starting from the origin, towards the all positive octant and until the plane $x = 2 - y$, ($x=y=z=0$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region is bound by $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$, $z = x^2 + 2$ and $x+y =2 $

So $z$ is bound below by xy-plane $(z = 0)$ and above by the parabolic cylinder. Rest of the bounds are correct.

The correct integral to find volume is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^2\int_0^{2-y}\int_0^{x^2+2} dz~dx~dy = \frac{16}{3}$

Comment: Just to clarify, since the region is in the first octant and $z=0$ is given, the bounds will be $z=0$ and $z=x^2+2$. But if it only stated that it is in the first octant and $z=0$ is not given, will the bounds still be $z=0$ and $z=x^2+2$ or will my attempt be correct?

Comment: @Kiel yes it will still be $0 \leq z \leq x^2 + 2$ because first octant would anyway mean the lower bound is $z  = 0$ for the given region.

Comment: I see, I understand now. Thank you for helping & clarifying!

Comment: Right. Sorry I forgot to click it!